# Firebase Functions: What are the Pros and cons of having two different functions for the same trigger?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a trigger when a video is uploaded for cloud storage. I have to

- Extract some frames and make API calls with it.
- Convert the video format and upload the storage.

My initial thought was to have two separate functions to handle the tasks. But it could also be in the same function trigger. 
Initial red-flags are timeouts and running out of memory. I wonder what are other pros and cons?. 
Costs/Performance/memory

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to just put it in one function trigger. As it will make it easier for you to maintain and refactor your code.

You don't have to worry about performance or memory, since Firebase Functions will scale and do the heavy lifting for you.

Unless the video that you want to convert and upload is in Gigbs. Then it's probably better if you do the conversion in another third-party service that's specialised in doing so.

You might want to check on Firebase Functions Quotas and Limits detail, and see if it still fit your need. [Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas)